# Adding property to ListView ColumnHeader Collection

Tags: c#, listview, columnheader

Is there any (preferably straight-forward) way to add a field/item to the ColumnHeader Collection in a UseControl that is based on the ListView.  We need to track an attribute for each column.
If you look at the picture, what we want to do is basically have a "MyField" attribute having value "My Value" associated with each column.
So far I've been researching how something like this might be done, but I don't seem to have found anything that looks quite like this. I suspect an ExpandoObject may somehow get involved, but my research into that is still in its infancy.
So, any quick ways to add properties to the Listview ColumnHeader?

Thanks all!

[image]

Comment: How would WinForms (?) or the ListView know how to use this new property?  I suspect you really want to do something with the LV *items*  (ie your data)not the columns

Comment: Essentially it would, I hope, be treated just like the "Text" column, but as an additional attribute that had information pertinent to our uses. Specifically, a field in a class or List of struct, so that we can link incoming data that conforms to variable name rules, to columns, which have meaningful string descriptions.  If there's another way to do that, please let me know!!